# Fetch value from input field and pass into the router link

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm new to the angular, so I just wanted simple approach to get the value from input field and pass that into the router link in anchor tag.

```html
<div>
  <form [formGroup] class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"> 
    <input
      class="form-control mr-sm-2"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search"
      name="searchValued"
      [(ngModel)]="searchedValue">
    <a [routerLink]="['/getSearchedBusiness', searchedValue]" class="btn btn-primary">Search</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please provide the Ts code also including your `Routes`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale here is the ts code


public searchedValue: string;

  constructor() {  }

  ngOnInit() {
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works well when the form element is removed from the code

```
<div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <!-- <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Login/Sign Up</button> -->
     <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="searchValued" [(ngModel)]="searchedValue"  >
     <a   [routerLink]="['/getSearchedBusiness', searchedValue]"    class="btn btn-primary" >Search</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you wanna a simple approach, you don't need to have a `form` to do that. You can use just the `[(ngModel)]` to achieve what you want. So, it's almost like you did:

component.html

```
<input
  class="form-control"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Search"
  [(ngModel)]="searchedValue">

  <a [routerLink]="['/getSearchedBusiness', searchedValue]" class="btn btn-primary">Search</a>
```

You can also do:

```
<a routerLink="/getSearchedBusiness/{{ searchedValue }}]" class="btn btn-primary">Search</a>
```

In your component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-search',
    templateUrl: './search.component.html'
  })
export class SearchComponent {
   public searchedValue: string;

   constructor () {
   }
}
```